# Passing an argument into a FOR loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I know I can simply write a `while` loop for this..

I'm just curious to know how to pass an `argument` like this:

```
   function i(a,z){

      for (a; a<2; z){

          //do something...

      }
   }
```

I tried

```
    i(0,a++);
    i(0,'a++');
    i(0,a=a+1);


    var z = "a= a+1";
    i(0,z);
```

and all didn't work.

---

**​[UPDATE]**

I know I can change the function into

```
   function i(a,z){

      for (a; a<2; a=a+z){

          //do something...

      }
   }
```

then

```
  i(0,1);
```

**but what I want to know here is how I can pass that `a=a+z` as an argument without changing my function...**

Comment: You can't... at least not *exactly* like that. *without changing my function*: There is no way.

Comment: If `2` is fixed, the whole approach seems to be a bit flawed though... it does not give you a lot of choice for the third part (`a += 1`), so why go through that hassle?

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah I know.. There are plenty ways to change it. But I'm just curious about the idea of passing `a=a+1` as an argument..

Comment: Ok... in that case your only choice would be to pass a function, like  @RhymecheaT showed in his/her answer. That would be the only possible to defer the evaluation of the expression you want to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I guess you would want something like this:

```
function i(a, z){
    for (a; a < 2; a = z(a)){
        //do something...
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
i(0, function(a) { 
     a++; 
     return a;
});
```

Note that it is very similar to what you have except that the last part of the for is a function.

Comment: `a++` won't affect the outer `a` though... you'd have to return it: `for (a; a<2; a = z(a))`

Comment: The idea is good, but in its current form it leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: My mistake. Not only did I not understood the question, i rushed to provide an incorrect answer. The way to do it would be like Felix Kling described in his comment.

Comment: @RhymecheaT: Nothing stops you from fixing your answer ;) (well, in this case I did it already...)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want this variant?

```
function i(start, end, delta){

      for (var i = start; i<end; i += delta) {

          //do something...

      }
}
```

Use it `i(0, 10, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function i(o){
    for (; o.a<2; o.z()){
        //do something...
        console.log('x');
    }
}
var o = {
    a:0, 
    z:function(o) {
        this.a++
    }
};

i(o);
```